# Prestashop how add new translation field to existing module(Paypal)?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I need to add new translation for the newly added word in the Paypal payment module.How it possible to add a new translation filed in the module paypal ?

Please help me to do this..

Answer (score 5):

If the new text is in the tpl

```
{l s='My new text' mod='paypal'}
```

If it's in a php file

```
$this->l('My new text')
```

Then you can translate it in admin tab

Tools > Translation : ps 1.4

Localisation > Translation : ps 1.5

Comment: You can find the translation files of your theme in /themes/your-theme-folder/lang/
And the translation files of modules in each modules folder
But I think you can't find new texts in those files.

Comment: I have added in my tpl file a translation segment, and I set up an existing module. However, in the admin panel, I don't see the new translation segment. I have emptied the cache just in case. Any help would be welcome :) @MarioRadomanana